# poco model generated in framewok 4.0 work well in framework 3.5?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco

does entity framework poco model generated in framework 4.0 work well in framework 3.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it will not work at all because Entity framework in .NET 3.5 doesn't support POCOs. If you need to use .NET 3.5, EF and POCO check this [POCO adapter](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFPocoAdapter).